# PHP MVC - adding more Views

Tags: php, model-view-controller, boilerplate

I recently implemented the following MVC code using this [tiny mvc boilerplate](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/create-your-first-tiny-mvc-boilerplate-with-php).
I did not want to use Zend or Symfony as I only require a small structure but i really need to expend this one slightly.

I am new to PHP so wondered if anyone has used this or knows how i go about adding another View. I have got the link version working which i use to load my layout but would like to add a Content section within this layout which is able to call other pages.

Any help with this would be great!

Comment: call it from that view? Or better, use a template.

Comment: Ok, that framework is just too basic for real world usage, you need to control the route of the script and that is hard coded into a single class so you may as well just call controller.php, I think its just meant to explain MVC... I recommend you look at this tutorial and learn from the source files. http://phpro.org/tutorials/Model-View-Controller-MVC.html

Comment: Thanks for your help guys. I had a feeling the example i used was far too basic.

Answer (score 0):

Gods below .. that video is horrible.

In that existing example, if you want to add another "view" (which is no really what view is), you will need another method in the controller:

```
class Controller
{
    // -- snip --
    // you need to change the constructor too
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->load = new Load;
        $this->model = new Model;
    }

    // -- snip --

    public function gallery()
    {
        $list = $this->model->get_urls();
        if ( count($list) > 0 )
        {
            $this->load->view('gallery.php' , $list);
        }
        else
        {
            $this->load->view('error.php', array(
                 'source' => 'gallery',
                 'reason' => 'empty'
            ));
        }
    }

    // -- snip --
}
```

And you also would need to change the *tinyMvc.php* file:

```
$c = new Controller;
$action = 'home';
if ( isset( $_GET['page']))
{
    $action = $_GET['page'];
}

if ( method_exists( $c, $action) )
{
    $c->{$action}();
}
else
{
    echo 'no such action !';
}
```

Anyway. Whole that "tutorial" uses the terms of MVC, that isn't really whats made there. His "view" is actually just a simple template. Which is not completely a thing to learn how to do for a beginner, but his implementation sucked too .. If you want to learn how to make simple native php templates, you might find [this article](http://codeangel.org/articles/simple-php-template-engine.html) quite useful.

Comment: Thanks tereško. I have since then decided to delete the above template and use another one. I am currently deciding between [PHPro](phpro.org/tutorials/Model-View-Controller-MVC.html) and [Symfony2] (http://symfony.com). I heard [Codeigniter] (http://codeigniter.com/) is good for beginners but i wonder if i will regret using such a basic one in the future.

Comment: @DVL , CodeIgniter (along with CakePHP) is one of the worst php frameworks out there. Avoid it whenever possible. The symfony2 is quite acceptable, but it might be way too complicated for someone of your level. Instead of trying to dig into MVC, you should be learning more about OOP .. that laws an principle that are associated with well written object oriented code.

Comment: Well i have a project to complete so really want to get stuck in. I should pick it up quickly so want to make sure i use the right tools. Would you recommend the PHPro MVC? Seems nice and lightweight allowing me to add things down the line, if needed.

Comment: @DVL, eecommend it? Definitely not. But as a stepping stone in learning proper MVC  this would do ok.

Comment: Thanks for your comments and help with this. I may use PHPro to start with - as long as it is lightweight and allows me to call different views using a template, it should be fine for now. Thanks!